# How to suppress Perl warnings emitted from within a loaded module's code?

Tags: linux, perl, module, warnings

My Perl program is reading data from a serial device attached through USB. Headlines of my script in pseudo-Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Device::SerialPort;
my $PortObj = tie( *$handle , "Device::SerialPort" , $PortName ) or die "Cannot open serial port: $!\n";
while ( 1 ) {
  my $readLength = read( $handle , my $frameData , $frameLength )
}
```

All works fine and even when I unplug the device from USB I'm able to recover from that situation, when the device file disappears and reappears. I can catch all errors spawned from my own script, but the loaded modules (Device::SerialPort) spawns warnings too and I don't want them to appear in my logging.

Can I add some sort of flag to my code so I don't see these specific warnings? It is important for me that only warnings from the module(s) are suppressed, not the warnings from my own script. Currently it looks like this:

```
[/dev/ttyUSB1]   0x0020 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AA 93 82 73 68 5E 58 : ............sh^X
[/dev/ttyUSB1]   0x0030 : 55 54 52 52 4F 4E 50 51 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : UTRRONPQP.......
Use of uninitialized value $count_in in addition (+) at /usr/lib/perl5/Device/SerialPort.pm line 2214.
Use of uninitialized value $string_in in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/lib/perl5/Device/SerialPort.pm line 2232.
[/dev/ttyUSB1] Restart required!
[/dev/ttyUSB1] Cannot open serial port: No such file or directory
[/dev/ttyUSB1] Cannot open serial port: No such file or directory
[/dev/ttyUSB1] Cannot open serial port: No such file or directory

[/dev/ttyUSB1]   0x0000 : 41 42 01 40 71 01 1C E4 80 99 80 80 80 80 00 00 : AB.@q...........
[/dev/ttyUSB1]   0x0010 : 00 03 00 00 83 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : ................
```

So it is about the two `Use of uninitialized value` warnings that I want to get rid of. The other warnings are my own logging.

- libdevice-serialport-perl 1.04-2build1
- perl v5.12.4

Comment: It would be a good idea to report those errors to the author.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try and intercept the warnings:

```
$SIG{'__WARN__'} = sub { warn $_[0] unless (caller eq "Device::SerialPort"); };
```

Comment: Tried, but unfortunately has no effect.

Comment: @jippie, Unless the module specifically overrides `$SIG{__WARN__}` (not likely) or if they're not actually warnings (yeah right), using `$SIG{__WARN__}` most certainly does work. It might just be a question of fixing the "if". s/Device::Serial/Device::SerialPort/, for starters.

Comment: Rats, yes it is `SerialPort` *not* `Serial`. Thank you ikegami.

Comment: Works :) I hadn't seen the typo either.

Answer (score 3):

Made a copy of the module in my home directory and added two lines:

```
$ diff SerialPort.pm /usr/lib/perl5/Device/SerialPort.pm 
2207,2208d2206
<     unless ( defined $count_in ) { $count_in = 0; }
<     unless ( defined $string_in ) { $string_in = ""; }
```

Which seems to work. Notified the author.